# I can't see the data saved on database table when running php artisan test

Tags: laravel-7

This is Laravel 7, I have this phpunit.xml

```
<server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
<server name="APP_IMAGES_PATH" value=""/>
<server name="FILESYSTEM_DRIVER" value="tests"/>
<server name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
<server name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
<server name="LOG_CHANNEL" value="tests"/>
<server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="test_db"/>
<server name="DB_DATABASE" value="test_db"/>
<server name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
<server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="redis"/>
<server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
<server name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
```

and my .env

```
TEST_DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
TEST_DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
TEST_DB_PORT=5432
TEST_DB_DATABASE=test_db
TEST_DB_USERNAME=laravel
TEST_DB_PASSWORD=password

APP_ENV=testing
```

but when this code

```
$item = new OrderData;
$item->integration = 'integration';
$item->external_reference = $this->xml_contents["order"]["order_id"];
$item->order_id = $this->xml_contents["order"]["order_id"];
$item->save();
```

was executed when running

```
php artisan test
```

I can't see it was save in database table `order_data` but on the next line

```
$orderData = OrderData::query()->where('external_reference', $orderId)->first();
```

$orderData contains data.

Why is that?